# Is it possible to use create a machine learning model to determine the best arbitrage opportunity

Tags: machine-learning

this might be a bit of an open question but I would just like to understand further on the subject as I am rather new to machine learning and arbitrage trading.

Would it be possible to develop a machine learning model to determine which arbitrage trading strategy would be best, in this case, I am focusing on simple exchange arbitrage (e,g. the immediate buying and selling of an asset) and triangular arbitrage.

Comment: Depends on your goal I would imagine. The ML models I've seen are mainly used for prediction.

Comment: It's possible. Do you need to use machine learning though?  It doesn't seem necessary with the information you have given.

Comment: In his case, would you just develop your own custom cost function, figure out some parameters on training data and then test it on out of sample data?  Would this be considered ML?